# change layout and template in zend dynamically according to the device(android tab,iphone,ipad) which the user use for browsing

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing an application, magazine store for PC and I have completed most of the work for pc, but the client also want to have the same thing in other android devices (load as web view).

Since these devices height and width varies the from that of PC so I need to get the device size and height in the most simple way, so that I can switch view according to the device.

Comment: what is the best way to get height, width and screen resolution ?? i have used js window.height and width property but i think its giving the correct value or the measurement is using different scale on different device.

Comment: maybe take a look at [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: currently i used that but i think it consumes little more time or resolving the device resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to see with Zend Framework/PHP (according to your question tags). Your question is more relative to Javascript/CSS.

I recommend you this awesome article: [Different Stylesheets for Differently Sized Browser Windows](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/) on CSS-Tricks. You can also take this website as a reference, their technique is really the best way to do it to me, but it requires a lot of work (and time) too.