# suggest a good practice for developing zend application for mobile device

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change layout and template in zend dynamically according to the device(android tab,iphone,ipad) which the user use for browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027193/change-layout-and-template-in-zend-dynamically-according-to-the-deviceandroid-t)

I am developing a magazine store that has to loaded as web view on different devices ,i have two approaches in mind.

1. changing the template and view path folder in bootstrap file according to the device
2. making different modules for different device .

   note:the device resolution, ht and width are already analyzed  according to the resolution template selection process has to be done.

suggest a better solution among above or share other ideas which u are having.

Comment: You've asked [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027193/change-layout-and-template-in-zend-dynamically-according-to-the-deviceandroid-t/10027520#10027520) a couple of days ago. Consider reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: Yes, if this question is essentially the same as the other one, further clarification/discussion should be on the other question. It's a big topic, which you'll have to do a fair bit of reading for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).